# Docker container cannot access internet

Tags: docker, containers, bridge

I'm on my second week of working through this problem and nothing on the internet has helped fix my issue.

The problem is that without specifying --net=host, I cannot access the internet from my docker containers.

```
/home/dnadave> docker run -it --net=host --rm debian:jessie ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=12.059 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=11.120 ms
^C--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.120/11.589/12.059/0.470 ms
/home/dnadave> docker run -it --rm debian:jessie ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
^C--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

I've disabled my firewall and flushed my iptables rules and followed many, many other suggestions in posts from many, many docker related issues that look like mine.  Nothing so far has enabled my containers to connect to the net.

Why do I care when I can access the net using --net=host?  Well, you can't build containers when the default networking doesn't work.

Here are some relevant details I've seen other posts ask:

```
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 2
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-254:2-1328636-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 1.973 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 105.4 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.61 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.146 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.03.01 (2015-05-15)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.12-1-default
Operating System: openSUSE Leap 42.1 (x86_64)
CPUs: 32
Total Memory: 125.9 GiB
Name: linux-3nwo
ID: 7MDY:2LCE:NMQ2:3INA:HL4A:LRTZ:VL43:TLBT:M5UN:PF7G:KKGN:AM6D
WARNING: No swap limit support
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:c5:53:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.xxx.82/23 brd 10.0.253.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fec5:5360/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:c5:53:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:7f:2d:f8:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:7fff:fe2d:f89c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
46: veth98c3765@if45: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:d2:9b:09:48:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::70d2:9bff:fe09:4890/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
docker0         8000.02427f2df89c       no              veth98c3765
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # ip route
default via 10.0.xxy.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp 
10.0.xxy.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.xxx.82 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1 
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 12M packets, 7205M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 573 packets, 48132 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 10M packets, 2311M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # iptables -L -n -t nat    
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Let me know if you need something else to help figure out why I can't get the default network bridge to work.

Note that in the above output, xxx and xxy are different subnet numbers.

Here is the output from tcpdump and iptables:

```
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # tcpdump -ni eth0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
09:33:44.694711 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.1 tell 10.0.253.189, length 46
09:33:44.707861 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 292
09:33:44.734664 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 49
09:33:44.815213 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.31 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:44.951684 IP 10.0.253.66.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:44.966217 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal], bridge-id 8000.40:b4:f0:b9:b2:81.82c4, length 43
09:33:44.986628 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.5 tell 10.0.253.30, length 46
09:33:45.116595 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.253.66 tell 10.0.252.154, length 46
09:33:45.117351 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.154 tell 10.0.253.66, length 46
09:33:45.259474 IP 10.0.253.82.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: 0*- [0q] 3/0/0 (Cache flush) SRV linux-3nwo.local.:0 0 0, (Cache flush) A 10.0.253.82, (Cache flush) TXT "name=linux-3nwo" "uuid=f73a028a-263b-42ed-a070-bafa703a2da7" "type=NoMachine" "port=0" "OS=openSUSE Leap 42.1 (x86_64)" "HW=Supermicro X9DAX" "mac=00:25:90:c5:53:60" "service=nx:4000" "ip=10.0.253.82;172.17.42.1;fe80::225:90ff:fec5:5360;fe80::42:7fff:fe2d:f89c;fe80::6810:94ff:fea6:3eea" (385)
09:33:45.273468 IP 10.0.253.20.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:45.316500 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 12, length 64
09:33:45.406752 IP 10.0.253.37.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:45.432241 IP 10.0.253.25.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:45.701715 IP 10.0.253.66.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:45.813602 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.31 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:45.828616 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.11 tell 10.0.252.187, length 46
09:33:45.844097 IP6 fe80::3cc4:9f10:cfc6:39ac.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:45.979351 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:45.979471 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:45.979545 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 854
09:33:45.997331 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 40
09:33:45.998852 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:46.005539 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 30
09:33:46.037852 IP 10.0.253.20.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:46.048897 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 30
09:33:46.141264 IP 10.0.253.37.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:46.196611 IP 10.0.253.25.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:46.302958 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 113
09:33:46.314737 IP 10.0.253.82.48551 > 10.0.252.3.53: 47613+ A? chatenabled.mail.google.com. (45)
09:33:46.317614 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 13, length 64
09:33:46.328701 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 49
09:33:46.339058 IP 10.0.252.3.53 > 10.0.253.82.48551: 47613 2/0/0 CNAME b.googlemail.l.google.com., A 216.58.216.167 (90)
09:33:46.339372 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [S], seq 1946932641, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 123005594 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:33:46.339722 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [S.], seq 1266324944, ack 1946932642, win 43690, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 1232193259 ecr 123005594,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:33:46.339787 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005594 ecr 1232193259], length 0
09:33:46.340738 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005594 ecr 1232193259], length 219
09:33:46.341189 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [.], ack 220, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193260 ecr 123005594], length 0
09:33:46.345530 IP6 fe80::515e:7529:ba62:109c.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:46.406369 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [P.], seq 1:4097, ack 220, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193279 ecr 123005594], length 4096
09:33:46.406425 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [.], ack 4097, win 293, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005611 ecr 1232193279], length 0
09:33:46.406556 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [P.], seq 4097:4192, ack 220, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193279 ecr 123005611], length 95
09:33:46.406596 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [.], ack 4192, win 293, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005611 ecr 1232193279], length 0
09:33:46.415570 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 220:482, ack 4192, win 293, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005613 ecr 1232193279], length 262
09:33:46.415702 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [.], ack 482, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193282 ecr 123005613], length 0
09:33:46.427730 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [P.], seq 4192:4486, ack 482, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193286 ecr 123005613], length 294
09:33:46.432424 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 482:535, ack 4486, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005617 ecr 1232193286], length 53
09:33:46.432527 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 535:585, ack 4486, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005617 ecr 1232193286], length 50
09:33:46.432540 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [P.], seq 4486:4584, ack 535, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193287 ecr 123005617], length 98
09:33:46.432695 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 585:627, ack 4584, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005617 ecr 1232193287], length 42
09:33:46.432840 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [.], ack 627, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193287 ecr 123005617], length 0
09:33:46.433160 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 627:2069, ack 4584, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005618 ecr 1232193287], length 1442
09:33:46.433280 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 2069:2107, ack 4584, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005618 ecr 1232193287], length 38
09:33:46.433294 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [.], ack 2069, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193287 ecr 123005618], length 0
09:33:46.446278 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [P.], seq 4584:4622, ack 2107, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193291 ecr 123005618], length 38
09:33:46.484848 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [.], ack 4622, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005631 ecr 1232193291], length 0
09:33:46.485009 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [P.], seq 4622:5489, ack 2107, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193303 ecr 123005631], length 867
09:33:46.485046 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [.], ack 5489, win 336, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005631 ecr 1232193303], length 0
09:33:46.486329 IP 10.0.253.82.38118 > 216.58.216.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 2107:2153, ack 5489, win 336, options [nop,nop,TS val 123005631 ecr 1232193303], length 46
09:33:46.489529 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 229
09:33:46.524219 IP 216.58.216.167.443 > 10.0.253.82.38118: Flags [.], ack 2153, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 1232193315 ecr 123005631], length 0
09:33:46.528035 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 33
09:33:46.580067 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 149
09:33:46.581176 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 20
09:33:46.581293 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 46
09:33:46.586292 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:46.586350 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:46.586398 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 817
09:33:46.604126 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 36
09:33:46.632662 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 30
09:33:46.768722 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 49
09:33:46.770637 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 63
09:33:46.789002 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 32
09:33:46.801044 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal], bridge-id 8000.40:b4:f0:b9:b2:81.82c4, length 43
09:33:46.813571 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 30
09:33:46.814971 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 43
09:33:46.858966 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.31 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:46.895047 IP 10.0.253.37.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:46.957553 IP6 fe80::b01a:80e7:8bb6:9151.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:46.957560 IP6 fe80::b01a:80e7:8bb6:9151.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:46.960984 IP 10.0.253.25.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:46.971896 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:46.972007 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:46.972111 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 899
09:33:46.972252 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 34
09:33:46.987867 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 36
09:33:46.988242 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 33
09:33:47.028542 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.22 tell 10.0.252.187, length 46
09:33:47.150542 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 69
09:33:47.150586 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 172
09:33:47.151005 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 49
09:33:47.200289 IP 10.0.253.188.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:47.268317 IP 10.0.252.122.138 > 10.0.252.255.138: NBT UDP PACKET(138)
09:33:47.268767 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.255 tell 10.0.252.143, length 46
09:33:47.318762 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 14, length 64
09:33:47.826000 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.31 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:47.868511 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.255 tell 10.0.252.143, length 46
09:33:47.912076 IP6 fe80::5119:e41f:69fb:571a.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:47.965641 IP 10.0.253.188.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:47.976067 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:47.976156 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:47.976214 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 889
09:33:47.979693 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:47.979768 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 1350
09:33:47.979833 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 917
09:33:47.979912 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 300
09:33:47.988005 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 36
09:33:47.994315 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 33
09:33:47.995542 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 33
09:33:48.019637 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 30
09:33:48.149231 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 88
09:33:48.162129 IP6 fe80::3144:581c:bddd:1174.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:48.174777 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 52
09:33:48.182153 IP6 fe80::d5a1:b9ed:5abf:e987.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:48.205805 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 130
09:33:48.206747 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 55
09:33:48.206985 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 43
09:33:48.209197 IP 173.194.33.118.443 > 10.0.253.82.57774: UDP, length 41
09:33:48.212576 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.3 tell 10.0.253.200, length 46
09:33:48.213464 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.253.200 tell 10.0.252.3, length 46
09:33:48.235155 IP 10.0.253.82.57774 > 173.194.33.118.443: UDP, length 40
09:33:48.319893 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 15, length 64
09:33:48.368223 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.253.25 tell 10.0.252.154, length 46
09:33:48.368497 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.154 tell 10.0.253.25, length 46
09:33:48.372105 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.109 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:48.385849 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.253.143 tell 10.0.252.104, length 46
09:33:48.386598 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.104 tell 10.0.253.143, length 46
09:33:48.423585 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.122 tell 10.0.252.121, length 46
09:33:48.468500 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.255 tell 10.0.252.143, length 46
09:33:48.636354 IP 10.0.253.82.58726 > 10.0.252.3.53: 48237+ A? careers.stackoverflow.com. (43)
09:33:48.662658 IP6 fe80::a40b:27e1:9478:e1be.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:48.696961 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal], bridge-id 8000.40:b4:f0:b9:b2:81.82c4, length 43
09:33:48.731101 IP 10.0.253.188.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:48.794708 IP6 fe80::4970:ce3b:d6f3:3195.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:48.824379 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.31 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:49.131326 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.5 tell 10.0.253.177, length 46
09:33:49.321019 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 16, length 64
09:33:49.323655 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.109 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:49.368507 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.255 tell 10.0.252.143, length 46
09:33:49.476222 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.22 tell 10.0.252.183, length 46
09:33:49.511487 IP 10.0.253.30.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:49.609076 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.5 tell 10.0.253.21, length 46
09:33:49.609781 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.253.21 tell 10.0.252.5, length 46
09:33:49.659080 IP6 fe80::a40b:27e1:9478:e1be.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
09:33:49.999318 IP 10.0.253.21.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 8c:89:a5:93:01:ce, length 300
09:33:49.999948 IP 10.0.252.5.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 311
09:33:49.999997 IP 10.0.252.3.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 311
09:33:50.268462 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.255 tell 10.0.252.143, length 46
09:33:50.277206 IP 10.0.253.30.137 > 10.0.253.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
09:33:50.321988 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.109 tell 10.0.253.199, length 46
09:33:50.322153 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 17, length 64
09:33:50.500890 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal], bridge-id 8000.40:b4:f0:b9:b2:81.82c4, length 43
09:33:50.592916 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.252.5 tell 10.0.253.45, length 46
^C
153 packets captured
154 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
linux-3nwo:/var/lib # iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here's a better view of iptables -t nat -L:

```
linux-3nwo:~ # iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !loopback/8           ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1):

With help from Jessie Ahrens at Stackengine.com, we were able to identify that the socket connection was the problem.  We found this by creating a new socket by hand and observing that the networking issues disappeared.  The final fix was to edit /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service from:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

to:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock $DOCKER_OPTS
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your Iptables rule, and also try to do tcpdump on the host port to check any packets going out of the box, when you are running the ping inside the container.
command: tcpdump -ni eth0, iptables -L -n (if you have ubuntu host).

UPDATE:

Looking at the Tcpdump, looks like your host in not doing the NATing, the request is sent with docker ip itself, which has no meaning outside your host:
09:33:46.317614 IP 172.17.0.8 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 13, length 64
You can try this command:"iptables -t nat -L". You should see something like this:
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere

try restart docker service: service docker restart or /etc/init.d/docker restart. It should fix this table. Refer this for [IPtables](https://serverfault.com/questions/705192/iptables-rule-set-so-that-a-docker-container-can-access-a-service-on-a-host-ip) fix.

Comment: I just added the output from those two commands to my original post.  They were too long to add as a comment here.

Comment: You wouldn't believe the number of times I've restarted the service.  I've deleted and reinstalled docker/iptables several times.  I've even upgraded the OS from OpenSuSE 13.2 to Leap 42.1.  Nothing has fixed this problem.

Comment: linux-3nwo:/var/lib # iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !loopback/8           ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: I've also seen and tried all of the suggestions in the IPTables link you posted.  No go...  What is odd is my rules do not change after trying to adjust them as the poster suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Check out that enable ip forwarding. It's very important.

on RHEL, CentOS, or Fedora, edit the .network file in /usr/lib/systemd/network/ on your Docker host (ex: /usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network) and add the following block within the [Network] section.

```
[Network]
...
IPForward=true
```

in my case I add IPForward=ipv4 and it solve problem

Notice that

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

not solve this problem for me, only changing network interface on host has result

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#ip-forwarding-problems