# What configuration should I provide in docker-compose.yml to allow a spring boot docker container to connect to a remote database?

Tags: database, spring-boot, networking, docker-compose, remote-server

I try to start 2 containers with the following docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  client-app:
    image: client-app:latest
    build: ./client-app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client-app:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:8000

  spring-boot-server:
    build: ./spring-boot-server/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./spring-boot-server:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
```

The spring boot server tries to connect to a remote database server which is on another host and network. Docker successfully starts the `client-app` containers but fails to start the `spring-boot-server`. This log is showing that the server crashed because it has failed to connect to the remote database:

```
2021-01-25 21:02:28.393  INFO 1 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-25 21:02:29.553 ERROR 1 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The Dockerfiles of both containers create valid images by which I can run manually the containers. It looks like there are some default network restrictions on containers started by a composing file.

Docker compose version running on Ubuntu:

```
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
```

=============================================

FURTHER INVESTIGATIONS:

I had created a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
CMD mysql -A -P 3306 -h 8.8.8.8 --user=root --password=mypassword -e "SELECT VERSION()" mydatabase
```

along with a `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  test-remote-db-compose:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

to test aside the connectivity alone with the remote database. The test passed with success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been misteriously solved, after doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772455/1353723) , a host mashine reboot and `docker-compose up --build`.