# http request from one container to another failed

Tags: docker-compose

I am new to docker compose and trying to find the reason of error
I have ubuntu 20, Docker version 24.0.7, Docker Compose version v2.21.0
I reduced code to minimal possible:
docker-compose.jml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    build: ./service1
    ports:
      - "3000:80"

  service2:
    build: ./service2
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
```

service2 app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from Service2!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Service2 listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

service1 app:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Make an HTTP request to service2
    const response = await axios.get('http://service2:80');
    res.send(`Response from Service1: ${response.data}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error making request to Service2:', error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Service1 listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Dockerfile for both services:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

I can access service2 by http://localhost:3001
Request to service1 using http://localhost:3000 hungs for about 3 minutes and then an error is thrown by service1: Error making request to Service2: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.23.0.3:80

I tried to send request from service1 to service2 using service name and service port.
I expected successful request but it can not be sent

Comment: check if your containers are in the same network: `docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Networks}}"` and try to ping service2 from service1

Comment: What are your respective Dockerfiles for the two services?

Comment: @PavelKravtsov 
same network for both: test_default

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε
I added Dockerfile content to the description

Comment: @PavelKravtsov  ping resulted in Error: Command failed: ping -c 3 service2:80, at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12), at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28), at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16), at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:457:11), at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28), at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12) { code: 1, killed: false, signal: null, cmd: 'ping -c 3 service2:80' }, stdout PING service2:80 (172.23.0.2): 56 data bytes, 3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an evident error, but I'll try to help, and here's where I would start in this case:

1. Despite the fact that `version` and `expose` are deprecated and likely ignored, and both containers are in the same network by default, I would add details to the compose file to make it as comprehensive as possible (trimming down once everything is working):

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  service2:
    build: ./service2
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
    networks:
      - services-network

  service1:
    build: ./service1
    depends_on:
      - service2
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - services-network

networks:
  services-network:
```

2. Add `EXPOSE 80` to dockerfiles
3. Try to ping `service2` container from `service1` container by container name with no ports specified. To ensure that the container is accessible by its name through DNS.
4. If container is not accessible by its name, try to replace container name with IP (in service code and for ping). To get a container IP use this: `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME`. Or you can configure your network submask to get static IP.

I'm not familiar with Node.js, but if the `.get('http://service2:80')` code is loaded into the localhost browser and executed there, the `service2` address won't be accessible because the browser is not in the same network as the `service2` container. There are multiple approaches to handle this, for example environment variables.

*UPD: As it turned out, in this case, the issue was with a broken docker network.*

Comment: Thank you. I added everything. Unfortunately same result :  connect ETIMEDOUT 172.27.0.2:80, I tried to ping using docker exec by ip, ip with port, service name, service name with port - no ping at all. It worth to mention - ping to external resources like google.com does not work either (ping to external resources works fine when start single container with docker run)

Comment: If you run compose file with two services: `image: node:20-alpine` and `command: ["ping", "google.com"]` / `command: ["ping", "service1"]` - only 2 rows for each service (image and command) and nothing else, will the ping work on these services?

Comment: Just `test-service2-1  | PING google.com (142.251.208.142): 56 data bytes` and nothing after. Same for another service

Comment: In that case, you need to investigate network issues. Off the top of my head, I can't think of the next steps other than restarting everything, updating Docker, and searching on Google. Sorry. If there are any new details, feel free to write here. I'll do my best to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found working solution here: [no internet inside docker-compose service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867602/no-internet-inside-docker-compose-service#answer-43772455)

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

After executing described commands everything start to work

Thank you for everybody!