# Docker container cannot access internet behind cisco vpn

Tags: docker, vpn

### My setup:

- Linux Mint 20
- Docker version 19.03.12
- Cisco AnyConnect 4.3.05017

### My Issue:

When I connect to my company's VPN I cannot access the internet through my docker containers.
e.g. running `docker run -it ubuntu apt update` will fail with the message
"Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'"

Disconnecting from VPN does **not** fix the issue. (see workaround #2)

I have two workarounds:

1. running docker with `docker run -it --net=host ubuntu apt update` will work fine, however, that is not a suitable workaround for my company's scripts and build system. It will do for ad-hoc jobs.
2. Disconnect from the VPN and run the following script (from https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36151):

```
# /bin/bash
docker system prune -a
systemctl stop docker
iptables -F
ip link set docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
systemctl start docker
```

will allow it to work again - but then I don't have access to my company's internal servers, which is also needed to build our software.

I have tried these things:

- Added DNS to daemon.json ([My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet))
- Fixing the resolv.conf ([My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet))
- https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers
- [Docker container can only access internet with --net=host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519615/docker-container-can-only-access-internet-with-net-host)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35519951/9496422
- and basically any other hit on the first two pages of google searching for "docker container no internet behind vpn"

Comment: I never found a good solution to this issue. I found a workaround by not using the Cisco Anyconnect client. Instead i configured openconnect to work with the company's VPN endpoints. It was quite a bit of work and i would not recommend that approach either.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine(Ubuntu) with Cisco AnyConnect and Docker, i found that VPN incorrectly works with iptables, so my bridge networks doesnt work.

Workaround is to add these rules:

```
 iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -I FORWARD -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

docker0 is a name of the default docker bridge network, for custom networks you need to replace "docker0" by network's interface name. Usually this name starts with "br-".

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to enable the setting "Allow local (LAN) access when using VPN (if configured)" in Cisco AnyConnect.

[cisco-anyconnect-preferences-window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Kys.png)

However, some companies doesn't allow to do this because of security policy.